# Probability - branching

Tags: probability

A population starts with 1 member: at t=1 , it can either divide with probability of p or dies with probability of 1-p. If it divides, then both of its children behave independently with the same options as above at t=2. What is the probability that no members in third generation? For what value of p is this probability equal to 0.5?

What I did:
P(NO MEMBER AT T=3)
=(1-p)+p(1-p)+p(1-p)
=-2p^2+p-1

I am not sure where is wrong, but p should be equal to 0.59697
Anyone can help?

Comment: Hint:  to kill all of them off by time $t=3$ either the first one dies or else she lives and her two children both die promptly.

Comment: @lulu thats what I did. but answer not right

Comment: You did not do it right.  $1-p$ is indeed the probability that the original parent dies.  The probability that she lives, but her children both die, is $p(1-p)^2$

Comment: @lulu why is not consider each child, like when parent divides, then p(1-p), the child dies and then again if the prob of another child die is p(1-p)?

Comment: think of it like throwing coins.  if you want $HTT$ then you need to multiply, so the probability is $(\frac 12)^3=\frac 18$.  If you had a weighted coin, that came up $H$ with probability $p$ (and therefore it comes up $T$ wiith probability $(1-p)$ we get $p(1-p)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T_i$ denote the number of members in the $i$-th generation so that $P(T_2=0)=1-p$ and $P(T_2=2)=p$.

Then: $$P(T_3=0)=$$$$P(T_3=0\mid T_2=0)P(T_2=0)+P(T_3=0\mid T_2=2)P(T_2=2)=$$$$1(1-p)+(1-p)^2p$$